# How to get datetime in Excel 2010 when copy-pasting cells from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

How do I automatically get the date time format from SQL server upon copying into Excel, without using the "right click-> Format Cells" option ?

options :
1. What is the shortcut key for date **and** time both in one cell ?

2. What is the SQL function to use on Datetime to get the entire datetime into Excel without having to format

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> is the shortcut key for the date in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The GETDATE() function in SQL will give you the current Date Time. Depending on the way you want to display your DateTime, you could use the Convert function to format your output the way you want.

For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)
```

gives the output in `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` format.

For more info regarding the different formats I would like to refer to MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx